# How to do not show picture on a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have Python code to create a picture file.
I run this on a Jupyter notebook.
I want to not show pictures on a Jupyter notebook.
I just want to save the picture file.

How to do not show picture on a Jupyter notebook?

> My code

```
import numpy
  .
  .
  .

fig = pl.figure(figsize=(10, 8)) 
# create subplots 
ax1 = pl.subplot2grid((2, 2), (0, 0)) 



# azimuth angle
#angle = 71
angle = angle_n

# Plot terrain (on ax1)
ax1, dem = wrl.vis.plot_ppi(polarvalues, 
                            ax=ax1, r=r, 
                            az=np.degrees(coord[:,0,1]), 
                            cmap=mpl.cm.terrain, vmin=0.)
ax1.plot([0,np.sin(np.radians(angle))*1e5],
         [0,np.cos(np.radians(angle))*1e5],"r-")
ax1.plot(sitecoords[0], sitecoords[1], 'ro')
annotate_map(ax1, dem, 'Terrain within {0} km range'.format(np.max(r / 1000.) + 0.1))

stitle=str('Site:{0}, El: {1}, Az: {2}, arc_sec:
{3}'.format(site_nm,el,angle_n,arc_s))
fig.suptitle(stitle, fontsize=12)
### Save figure file
fig.savefig(DAGR)
```

Comment: You could clear the console it after it puts the picture.

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000  how to clear the console?

Comment: Add `;` by the end of the cell whose output you want to hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `;` at the end of the cell whose output you want to hide.